# cnd_broadcast only wakeup threads who wait before the broadcast

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, c11

i've found weird behavior of `cnd_broadcast`
i run 2 threads, one of them is busy doing something.
and one of them is waiting for a new job.
and the main thread call `cnd_broadcast` to inform all threads that there's no work left so they can return.
then main waiting for chid threads to return `thrd_join`.
but **not all** child threads get informed. only the one who's waiting before the broadcast get informed.
and the other threads stuck waiting signal.
is this what it suppose to happen?

Comment: `cnd_broadcast` is described on cppreference as `Unblocks all thread that currently wait on condition variable pointed to by cond`

Comment: hm... so that is the expected behavior.
so, how to inform the incoming threads ?

Comment: Condition variables have an associated mutex. You need to use that mutex to properly synchronize access to your shared resource(s).  A thread shouldn't be able to even get to waiting on a condition variable without locking that mutex.

Comment: `cnd_wait` accept **mutex** as the second argument. i think it does it automatically. is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turns out its expected and documented.
[cppreference > cnd_broadcast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/cnd_broadcast)

Comment: It sounds like you're not using the associated mutex, state protected by the mutex, and predicate on that state to make the decision whether to call `cnd_wait`. That is the root of your problem.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE thanks for the response. but is it allowed to lock the mutex that is used by conditional variable using `mtx_lock`?

Comment: i've found the answer. but i'm not yet found any solution or alternative.

Comment: Yes, the mutex **must** be locked in order to call `cnd_wait`, and generally should be locked when you call `cnd_broadcast` or `cnd_signal` since you need to modify the mutex-protected state in order to have reason to signal.